# Two List(Of String), when I add a value to one it gets added to the other

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting the folders in two different directories and putting their names into two listviews, but if one folder name exist in only one directory I would like to enter nothing into the other list and vice versa, unless the folder name is in both, then I just want the name in both lists.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Private folders As New List(Of String), oFolders As New List(Of String), AllFoldrs As New List(Of DirectoryInfo), CurFdr As DirectoryInfo
Private Sub Get_LVItems()
    folders.Clear() : oFolders.Clear() : CurLV.Items.Clear() : AllFoldrs.Clear() 'Empty folders List and CurrentLV items
    Dim LV As ListView = CurLV, oLV As ListView = OtherLv
    Dim Pth As String = CurTV.SelectedNode.Name, oPth As String = ""
    Dim Dinfo As New DirectoryInfo(Pth), oDinfo As DirectoryInfo = Nothing
    Dim TmpFoldrs As New List(Of DirectoryInfo), oTmpFoldrs As New List(Of DirectoryInfo)
    If Not IsNothing(OtherTV.SelectedNode) Then
    End If
    If TVs_Syncd Then
        oPth = OtherTV.SelectedNode.Name : oDinfo = New DirectoryInfo(oPth)
        TmpFoldrs.AddRange(Dinfo.GetDirectories) : oTmpFoldrs.AddRange(oDinfo.GetDirectories)
        AllFoldrs.AddRange(Dinfo.GetDirectories) : AllFoldrs.AddRange(oDinfo.GetDirectories)
        AllFoldrs.Sort(AddressOf SrtAllFdrs)
        Do While AllFoldrs.Count > 0
            CurFdr = AllFoldrs(0)
            Dim Found_fdr As DirectoryInfo = Nothing, oFound_fdr As DirectoryInfo = Nothing
            For Each fdr As DirectoryInfo In TmpFoldrs
                If fdr.Name = CurFdr.Name Then Found_fdr = fdr : Exit For
            Next
            If IsNothing(Found_fdr) Then folders.Add(Nothing) Else folders.Add(Found_fdr.FullName)
            For Each ofdr As DirectoryInfo In oTmpFoldrs
                If ofdr.Name = CurFdr.Name Then oFound_fdr = ofdr : Exit For
            Next
            If IsNothing(oFound_fdr) Then oFolders.Add(Nothing) Else oFolders.Add(oFound_fdr.FullName)
            AllFoldrs.RemoveAll(AddressOf RemDirs)'After adding a folder to both collections (folders & oFolders) all instances of that folder get removed from AllFolders
        Loop
        LoadListView(oLV)
        folders.Clear()
        folders = oFolders
        LoadListView(LV)
    Else
        folders.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(Pth))
        LoadListView(LV)
    End If
End Sub
```

two functions:
for removing all instances of the folder name just processed and
the sort function for sorting AllFoldrs after adding all the folder names to it:

```
Public Function RemDirs(dir As DirectoryInfo) As Boolean
    Return dir.Name = CurFdr.Name
End Function
Public Function SrtAllFdrs(ByVal X As DirectoryInfo, ByVal Y As DirectoryInfo) As Integer
    Return X.Name.CompareTo(Y.Name)
End Function
```

I add both directories folders to AllFolders and each directories folders to their own Tmp List.
In the first For Each loop, I see if the current folder name exists in tmp list, if it does I put the value into Found_fdr then when I add it to the list(Of String) I am using to fill list A, it gets added to the other list(Of String) at the same time. I's baffling me!
This is much more to the point than my last question that got no answers, which really didn't surprise me. Anyone? Please...

Comment: 1) What does `LoadListView()` do and why is there `folders.Clear()` and `folders = oFolders` between the calls to `LoadListView(oLV)` and `LoadListView(LV)`? 2) I recommend that you do not use `:` to put more than one statement on a line - it tends to make it harder to see what is going on. Even variable declarations are easier to see if there is only one per line.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you add the subdirectories from both directories into one list (`AllFoldrs`) and then try to separate them out again. Would it not be simpler to work with them separately? So, `folders = New DirectoryInfo(CurTV.SelectedNode.Name).GetDirectories().OrderBy(Function(a) a.Name).Select(Function(b) b.Name).ToList()` and `oFolders = New DirectoryInfo(OtherTV.SelectedNode.Name).GetDirectories().OrderBy(Function(a) a.Name).Select(Function(b) b.Name).ToList()`?

Comment: @Andrew Morton I have got into habits. I kind of realized my code was going to be an irritant, I use what I can make work and though I have dabbled with SQL I tend to steer clear of it, I mean those two lines don't make much sense to me I'm afraid. LoadListView fills the ListView :) I have found the problem, it is indeed 'folder = oFolders'. Unexpected result. LoadListview loads items from folders so I want to empty folders and put oFolders items into folders to load the second ListView. Thanks though for the reply. This question made me think about the problem more clearly.

Comment: Glad to hear you've made progress. Those two lines are actually [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), which goes straight into your code, no SQL involved, and would replace the code in the `If TVs_Syncd Then` which gets the directories. I just noticed, they should select the .FullName, not the .Name property.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thanks! I think one of the best feelings for me is when I solve a problem like this one, after so many runs with all folders showing in one ListView and none in the other, then, there they are, just as they should be! It just feels so good :) I am stuck in the past I'm afraid, using things I am new too usually incurs a considerable time investment when there is no one pointing me in the right direction, but I do seem to make progress all the same.My knowledge grows slowly. This site is in fact my main tutor!